# Saving a JS Variable to Local Storage Passed from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When a build name is clicked the inner html is passed into a JavaScript variable loadDump then passed over to PHP.

```
    $.ajax({
  url:"http://custom-assembly.tcad.co.uk/wp-content/themes/custom-assembly/grp-enclosure/load.php",
  method: "post",
  data: { loadDump: JSON.stringify( loadDump )},
  success: function(res){
   var key_map_obj = '<?php echo $key_map_loaded; ?>';
   console.log(key_map_obj);


     var key_map_obj_string = key_map_obj;

     localStorage.setItem("key_map_obj_string", key_map_obj_string);
     console.log(localStorage);
  }
})
```

Once this happens the php in load.php executes. The loadDump variable is used in a sql query to find the matching field.

```
$loadDump =   wp_unslash( $_POST['loadDump'] );


      $table_name= $wpdb->prefix. 'product_configurator';
        $DBP_results= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE keymap_key = $loadDump");
        $DBP_current_user = get_current_user_id();


     foreach($DBP_results as $DBP_cols){
        $user_id= $DBP_cols->user_id;
        $enclosure_type= $DBP_cols->enclosure_type;
        $keymap_key= json_decode($DBP_cols->keymap_key, true);
         $key_map_loaded=json_decode($DBP_cols->key_map, true);

          } 



          ?>
```

How can i get $key_map_loaded to pass to the JavaScript and save in the local storage using Ajax.

Comment: `<? $key_map_loaded; ?>` does nothing. You should add `php` to the opening tag and add `echo`. I'm not familiar with `wp_unslash` but I'd prefer parameterizing the query

Comment: Instead of returning JS (that won't execute when it's loaded using ajax) in your Ajax response, just return the data in JSON format. Then you can put your JS code in your `success`-callback in your ajax request instead that uses the JSON-data.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Great Thats working, that was simple. Only issue now is its storing <? $key_map_loaded; ?> which i thought this is how you convert php to a js variable it should be showing an array

Comment: Unless you have short tags enabled in your php.ini (which is disabled by default since a bunch of versions back), you need to open PHP using `<?php` or it won't know it's PHP. And, as the first comment also mentions, you need to _echo_ the variable.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Updated the code on the thread, still echos the php code rather than the array.

Comment: Is this a `js` file or `php` file? How are you running it? It displays `<?php ...` on the page, or what exactly do you see?

Comment: I would recommend going through a couple of Ajax tutorials so you understand what it is and what it does.

Answer (score 1):

In you php file try to return the result :

```
e loadDump variable is used in a sql query to find the matching field.

$loadDump =   wp_unslash( $_POST['loadDump'] );


      $table_name= $wpdb->prefix. 'product_configurator';
        $DBP_results= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE keymap_key = $loadDump");
        $DBP_current_user = get_current_user_id();


     foreach($DBP_results as $DBP_cols){
        $user_id= $DBP_cols->user_id;
        $enclosure_type= $DBP_cols->enclosure_type;
        $keymap_key= json_decode($DBP_cols->keymap_key, true);
        $key_map_loaded=$DBP_cols->key_map;

          } 

        echo $key_map_loaded;

          ?>
```

Then in the JavaScript receive it for the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"load.php",
  method: "post",
  data: { loadDump: JSON.stringify( loadDump )},
  success: function (data) {
         var key_map_obj = data;
           console.log(key_map_obj);


           var key_map_obj_string = (key_map_obj);

           localStorage.setItem("key_map_obj_string", key_map_obj_string);
           console.log(localStorage);
     },

})
```